# How to properly count rows in table2 related to items in table1 with clause non related to table1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have simple magazine, and have tables with posts, comments, categories, etc. When listing single category, I want to have sum of comments per post in a listing, but that number is just wrong and it is driving me crazy. Note that single post can be in multiple categories.

Here are the simple tables structures

```
posts
id | title | categoryid | content | published
---------------------------------------------

comments
id | postid | comment
---------------------

category_rel
postid | categoryid
-------------------

categories
id | category
-------------
```

I use following sql (simplified to this example):

```
SELECT posts.*, categories.id AS categoryid, 
  categories.category AS categorytitle, 
  COUNT(comments.postid) AS CNT 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.postid 
INNER JOIN category_rel ON posts.id = category_rel.postid 
INNER JOIN categories ON category_rel.categoryid = categories.id 
WHERE posts.published=1 
GROUP BY posts.id;
```

This statement is giving me wrong results, sometning like it's cumulating number of categories post is member of and multiplying with actual number of comments. If I remove category part of SQL (which is not good, I need category Id and name) I receive proper values:

```
SELECT posts.*, COUNT(comments.postid) AS CNT 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.postid 
WHERE posts.published=1 
GROUP BY posts.id;
```

To be more specific:
One of posts have 1 comment and it is member of 7 categories. value CNT is going to 7, not 1.

Any idea how to change first SQL to get proper values?

Comment: GROUP BY posts.id = is it correct?  May be you need GROUP BY comments.postid?

Comment: No. When grouping by comments.postid will not get correct value for each post. Or probably will get all equal values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count the comments per post - not per category. So one way of achieving this would be to do the count first (in a subselect as MySQL has no CTE so far) and then join the results into category table:

```
SELECT countpost.*, categories.id AS categoryid, 
   categories.category AS categorytitle  
  FROM 
  -- subselect post and comment count
  (
    SELECT posts.*, count(comments.postid) as CNT FROM posts 
     LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.postid 
       WHERE posts.published = 1
       GROUP BY posts.id
  ) as countpost
  -- join category table
INNER JOIN category_rel ON countpost.id = category_rel.postid 
INNER JOIN categories ON category_rel.categoryid = categories.id ;
```

See this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9c6f/1